# How do I delete all of the same elements in a list?

Tags: python

I am having some trouble trying to do this.

I have this list with same elements.
I want to output only the unique elements. I don't even want the numbers that were duplicated.

for ex.

```
list = [1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5]

result: [3, 4]
```

I've been Googling this, but the post usually would talk about resulting such: 1, 3, 4, 5. which is not what I'm looking for.

please help!

Comment: Duplicate looks for items occuring more than once but your solution would be the same but `== 1`

Comment: list(set(l)); don't use the variable name list.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import collections
a = [1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5]
print([item for item, count in collections.Counter(a).items() if count == 1])
```